Is there a way to build a library with the vite build --watch option and restart the server after the build is completed?
When using the vite build --watch option to build a library, the build process works correctly whenever the library is modified. However, the server running with vite dev does not restart automatically, requiring a manual restart each time.
Is there a way to detect changes in the library files built by vite build --watch and automatically restart the vite dev server?
